# How to set default values to fields in Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I added a filed company(It's a char field), when creating a payment ,I want to set default value.
When creating new payment, the value wasn't displayed in the form view . But , when printing 'my_company' , I got the correct result.
What's wrong please?

```
class AccountPayment(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.payment"    

 @api.model
    def get_company(self):
        if self.move_type == 'in_invoice':
            my_company = self.env.user.company_id.name
            self.company = my_company

        else:
            self.company = ''

    company = fields.Char(string='Company   ', default=get_company)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try this:
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', 'Company', default=lambda self: self.env['res.users'].browse(self.env.uid).company_id.id)
this will fetch current login user's company and assign it in that field

Comment: @Muhammad Yusuf, the field which I added is a char field , I wouldn't change it to Many2one field , also , I had another condition of move_type. That's why I added the function 'get_company'  where I can add the condition. Thanks.

Comment: When you create a new payment, the move_type value is empty, so the result will always be empty quotes.

Comment: @Tiki  , yes ,also, the problem is still  when I tried with: if self.payment_type == 'outbound' , how can I get the correct condition to distinguish between payment of supplier and customer ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value.
Here is the correct code

```
class AccountPayment(models.Model):
     _inherit = "account.payment"    


    def get_company(self):
        if self.move_type == 'in_invoice':
            my_company = self.env.user.company_id.name
            return my_company
        else:
            return None

    company = fields.Char(string='Company Name', default=get_company)
```

Comment: I still have problem on condition if  self.move_type == 'in_invoice',it is not entering in if condition;   I tried with: if self.payment_type == 'outbound' ,I got same problem. Any help please? Thanks

Comment: I got always a 'False' value in payment_type .